# Find the regions that get split in $\Bbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\frac{z+i}{z-i}$, then let lines be

$$L_1= \{z \in \Bbb{C}: \text{Im$z$=$1$}\}$$
and

$$L_2= \{z \in \Bbb{C} : \text{Im$z$=$-1$}\}$$

and the circle $S^1$ which divide the complex region into five sections. Describe the corresponding regions under the image of $f$.

any hints/tips greatly appreciated in advance!

Comment: why the down vote? Im only trying to learn!

Comment: Well, for starters, what is the image of $f$ and draw a sketch to determine which five sections are in consideration. (I did not downvote)

Comment: Will do! @AlvinL could I get back to you if Im stuck

Comment: so I get that $1$ gets sent to $i$ and $-1$ gets mapped to $-i$ but where else do I go from here? @AlvinL

Comment: does $0$ get mapped to $-1$ or $-i$ @AlvinL

Comment: Hint: This is a Mobius transformation, which maps circles and lines to circles and lines. In fact the unit circle will be mapped to a line (since $i$ gets mapped to $\infty$) so your calculations already show that this line is the imaginary axis

Comment: so far I have points $(1,i)$ and $(-1,-i$) @Andrew

Comment: so will I end up with a line and two circles? @Andrew

Comment: In a Mobius transformation, lines and circles get mapped to lines when they pass through the pole, which in this case is at $z = i$. Therefore the unit circle and line $Im(z) = 1$ will both get mapped onto lines. You already have two of those points from the unit circle,  $i$ and $-i$, so clearly it maps onto the imaginary axis. I will let you figure out what line the $Im(z) = 1$ line maps onto. And finally the line $Im(z) = -1$ does not pass through the pole so it will be mapped to a circle. Try testing values of $z$ to determine these shapes

Comment: Since you seem to be confused, to make this very clear the line $Im(z) = 1$ is the set of points $x + i$ for some $x$. plug in $z = x + i$ and see what kinds of points you get

Comment: I think I got it! the second line maps to a circle of radius 1/2 centered at 1/2? @Andrew

Answer (score 0):

My answer has the goal to be a big hint, to guide you solving the exercise. But the one solving it should be you! I upvoted, don't mind about downvotes, mean people are everywhere.

As said in the comments $f$ is a Möbius transformation, which is an [automorphism of the Riemann Sphere $\overline{\Bbb C}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation), which can be thought as the complex plane $\Bbb C$ together with an additional point which makes it a compact space; one usually refers to this point as the infinity point $\infty$. This can be made rigorous, but here you can think think that \begin{align*}
\lim_{|z|\to+\infty}z&=\infty\\
1/0&=\infty\\
1/\infty&=0
\end{align*}
and these rules defines completely the behaviour of this new point.

Very informally, from a topological point of view, you can think at the complex plane $\Bbb C$ as... just a plane, and at $\infty$ as the unique point where you tend whenever your modulus gets indefinitely large; so it is a sort of "boundary" of your plane, which attracts the points of the plane as their modulus is bigger and bigger: if you imagine $\infty$ to be any point on some other plane parallel to $\Bbb C$, then your plane deforms to a sphere in $\Bbb R^3$, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere#As_a_sphere).

So, topologically we can think $\overline{\Bbb C}$ as the unit sphere $\Bbb S^2=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\;:\;x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ (it's easy to construct an homeomorphism between these two objects).

This forward is important because now we can better state a very important property of the Möbius transformations:

> Every Möbius transformation $f\colon\overline{\Bbb C}\to\overline{\Bbb C}$ maps circles of $\overline{\Bbb C}$ into circles of $\overline{\Bbb C}$.

Now we can distinguish two different kind of circles in $\overline{\Bbb C}$:
circles touching $\infty$ and circles which don't.

The former are straight lines in $\Bbb C$, the latter are usual (euclidean) circles.

So:

- What kind of objects $f(L_1)$, $f(L_2)$ and $f(\Bbb S^1)$ are? You can write an explicit description of them!
- I said that Möbius transformations are automorphisms of $\overline{\Bbb C}$: this means that since $L_1,\;L_2$ and $\Bbb S^1$ are either disjoint or they touch each other at most in one point, their images will behave the same!
- The interior of three of the five regions can be described as
  \begin{align*}
  &\{z\in\Bbb C\;:\;|z|<1\}\;;\\
  &\{z\in\Bbb C\;:\;\Im z>1\}\;;\\
  &\{z\in\Bbb C\;:\;\Im z<-1\}\;.
  \end{align*}
  Question: if $|z|<1$, what can we say about $|f(z)|$? Similarly for the other two regions. The two regions I didn't write can be understood by exclusion, once one study these first three.